# drawRect, fillRect, scale not matching up

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm trying to do some very simple drawings but I cant seem to get the result I need.

```
    /* Draw Title Bar */
    int w = window.getWidth();
    int h = 10;
    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);

    BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(1.0f,BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
            BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
    g2d.setStroke(stroke);


    g2d.fillRect(window.getX(), 
            window.getY(), w, h);



    /* Draw Window Border */
    g2d.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2d.drawRect(window.getX(), 
            window.getY()+h, 
            window.getWidth(), 
            window.getHeight());
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.drawLine(window.getX(), 50, window.getX()+window.getWidth(), 50);
```

With `g2d.scale(2.0, 2.0)` the result looks like:

[image]

It's not lining up properly. With scale=1.0 it alines correctly on the left side, but it's off on the right side. Is this an issue of scaling? I know that the edges of fillRect and drawRect are `x+w+1`/`x+w` but even if you adjust for that it still doesn't align properly.

Comment: if you are going to use fancy new strokes deal with it

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Show a drawing or image of the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from filling the upper rectangle - you should also draw it. As you can see there is no border for him.

Comment: this is misleading; he doesnt need to bring own fancy new libraries and the god of the world; he needs to correctly specify the lengths